How can I retrieve data saved using FileStream on a remote non-domain PC with SQL Server and C#?
I have a table that contains a field enabled for FileStream and it saves the information correctly.
Using the code indicated by the Microsoft guide (text), I can retrieve file information on a local server. As soon as I connect to a remote server (using the IP address) with SqlConnection, an error message appears saying "Incorrect username or password".
Below is the code I'm analyzing.
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=true;Password=sensure;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=DataTest;Data Source=" + "192.168.1.122" + "\\SQLEXPRESS" + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=True;encrypt=false");
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
...
                sqlConnection.Open();

                sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT RawImage.PathName()"
                    + " FROM DEFECTS";

                String filePath = null;

                Object pathObj = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                if (pathObj != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    filePath = (string)pathObj;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Get PathName FAILED!");
                }

                SqlTransaction transaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction("mainTransaction");
                sqlCommand.Transaction = transaction;

                sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT()";

                Object obj = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                byte[] txContext = (byte[])obj;


                SqlFileStream sqlFileStream = new SqlFileStream(filePath, txContext, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileOptions.None, 0);

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

You can't combine integrated security and user/password. Do you want to use Windows login (integrated=true) or Sql Server login (integrated=false)

^^ In other words: It's probably simply your connection string and is not related to the actual db operation you are attempting to do.

@siggemannen I tried setting Integrated Security to true and removing the User and Password, but it didn't work. I also tried removing Integrated Security and leaving the User and Password, but it still didn't work. The problem occurs when I try to connect remotely and I've used the connection string from the code.

I think filestream require windows auth, but are your servers on same domain? Also, doesn't works tells nothing, write the query string and respective error you're getting, and the stacktrace of relative length

You're right, my servers aren't in the same domain.

Use the full quaified domain name, not the IP address, if you want to use Active Directory authentication (aka Windows Authentication or Integrated Security). If you don't have an AD domain, or the server is not domain joined, then the whole thing is moot, and you can only use SQL Authentication. It's unclear what username and password you expected to use.

Also what is the file path you are seeing? Does your user actually have access to it?
